# How do I make a HTML div go under another div?

Tags: css, html, rows

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content1">
    <div id="text1">This text floats left</div>
    <div id="images1"><img src="img.jpg" /></div> <!--Floats right-->
</div>
<div id="content2">Text 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to do this, and try to make a layout like a table with two rows with the text floating left and the image floating right in the top row, all that comes up is that the content2-div is squashed into the content1-div. How can I keep them separate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `clear:both;` on your #content2 div

If you really wanna learn everything about floats, check out this amazing tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Comment: That was a super useful article. I totally didn't want to read it, but it was really intuitive after and not hard to do. Nice find.

Answer (score 2):

Use `clear:both;` on your content#2

Answer (score 2):

Apply:

```
#images1{
 float:right;   
}

#content2{
 clear:both;   
}
```

and fix your html markup

```
<div id="images1"><img src="img.jpg" /> <!--Floats right-->
```

close the div:

```
<div id="images1"><img src="img.jpg" /> <!--Floats right--></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `<div id="images1">` :)

Answer (score 0):

use 'clear:both' on content2 div

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to add another div before `<div id="content2">Text 2</div>` which will be  `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

clear your floats. 
Here is an article describing whats going on: [Clearing A Float Element](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed off `<div id="images1">`. If this div is closed and the Content divs arenot float left then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden` on your content1 div will make it expand to include all floated children. (Of course, this will hide non-floated overflowing content.)